# Bot Framework Error Exception: State size exceeded configured limit

Tags: bots

I'm using microsoft bot framework for my school project. I'm fairly new at this. After attempting the following code, I get the exception.

```
 await context.PostAsync("Let me recommend you");
 await context.PostAsync(recommendValue);
 if ((Px == null || Rx == null))
   {
                            await GoThere(context);
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

> at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ErrorHandling.d__2 1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---       \r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>         (Task task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotStateExtensions.d__13.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception         was
>   thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at 
>         System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ConnectorStore.
>         -SaveAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n---
>         End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)         \r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.CachingBotDataStore.d__10.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n         at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.CachingBotDataStore.-FlushAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
>         \r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n         at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.BotDataBase`1.
>         d__9.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous
>   location where exception was thrown ---\r\n           at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)         \r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTaskManagerBotDataLoader.d__12.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown 
>         ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>         (Task task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.d__3.MoveNext()
>         \r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n         at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.
>         d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n           at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)         \r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializeByConversation.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n---          End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n         at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.
>         d__5.MoveNext()"

Comment: Could you add more detail to your code, and explain a little about what it's supposed to do?

Comment: I stumbled across the same problem. Any solutions?